How to Ensure TypeScript Enforces Property Constraints Based on Input Object Keys?
I'm working with TypeScript and trying to ensure that the return type of a function accurately reflects the properties that are present in the input object after mapping. Specifically, I want TypeScript to enforce type constraints so that accessing non-existent properties on the returned object results in a compile-time error.
My current code:
enum MetadataKeys {
  NATURE = 'nature',
  BUDGET_YEAR = 'budget_year',
}

const metadataKeysMapper: Record<string, MetadataKeys> = {
  cdNatureza: MetadataKeys.NATURE,
  natureza: MetadataKeys.NATURE,
  cd_natureza: MetadataKeys.NATURE,
  SiglaNatureza: MetadataKeys.NATURE,
  nuAnoOrcamento: MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR,
  ordem_orcamentaria: MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR,
  nu_ano_orcamento: MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR,
  Orcamento: MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR,
  anoOrcamento: MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR,
};

type MetadataResponse<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends keyof typeof metadataKeysMapper
    ? (typeof metadataKeysMapper)[K]
    : never]: K extends keyof typeof metadataKeysMapper ? T[K] : never;
};

export function processMetadata<T extends Record<string, any>>(
  metadata: T,
): MetadataResponse<T> {
  const processedMetadata: Partial<Record<MetadataKeys, any>> = {};

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(metadata)) {
    if (key in metadataKeysMapper && value) {
      processedMetadata[metadataKeysMapper[key]] = value;
    }
  }
  return processedMetadata as MetadataResponse<T>;
}

Expected result:
const input = { natureza: 'comum' };
const result = processMetadata(input);

// Accessing valid property
console.log(result.nature); // should work

// Accessing invalid property
console.log(result.budget_year); // should raise a TypeScript error

Problem:
The TypeScript compiler is not raising an error when accessing non-existent properties on the result object. I expected accessing result.budget_year to cause a compile-time error.

It seems like the type of result is such that it gets keys that are the values of the MetadataKeys  enumeration.. budget_year is one of those values. It's not any invalid property: Typing result.blah raises a TypeScript compilation error as expected, for example.

You've thrown away the information you care about by annotating metadataKeysMapper as Record<string, MetadataKeys>. Let TS infer the type and use a const assertion so it knows which outputs go with which inputs. After you tweak some of your other type issues, that gives you the behavior from this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz this solved my problem. Thank you very much!

If you annnotate the type of metadataKeysMapper as Record<string, MetadataKeys> like
const metadataKeysMapper: Record<string, MetadataKeys> = { ⋯ };

then you are effectively discarding any more specific information from the initializing value.  That means keyof typeof metadataKeysMapper is just keyof Record<string, MetadataKeys> which is string.  TypeScript has no idea which particular keys might be there, or which values might be at which keys.

If you want to keep track of the specific properties in the initializer, then you should just let TypeScript infer the type of metadataKeysMapper from that initializer, so you should remove the annotation:
const metadataKeysMapper = { ⋯ };

If it matters that you check that metadataKeysMapper is assignable to Record<string, MetadataKeys>, you can use the satisfies operator to do so:
const metadataKeysMapper = { ⋯ } satisfies Record<string, MetadataKeys>;

And furthermore, if you want TypeScript to keep track of which enum members exist at which keys (that is, you want to tell the difference between the literal types of MetadataKeys.NATURE and MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR), then you should use a const assertion to ask for such narrow inference:
const metadataKeysMapper = { ⋯ } as const satisfies Record<string, MetadataKeys>;


Once you do that, you'll find that processMetadata()'s output behaves as you expected:
const input = { natureza: 'comum' };
const result = processMetadata(input);
console.log(result.nature); // okay
console.log(result.budget_year); // error!
//                 ~~~~~~~~~~~

Note that you might need to tweak the implementation of processMetadata because now metadataKeysMapper is not seen as allowing all possible string keys. The easiest way is to widen metadataKeysMapper back to Record<string, MetadataKeys> inside that function before indexing into it:
function processMetadata<T extends Record<string, any>>(metadata: T) {

    // copy to widened variable, 
    const mkm: Record<string, MetadataKeys> = metadataKeysMapper

    const processedMetadata: Partial<Record<MetadataKeys, any>> = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(metadata)) {
        if (key in mkm && value) { // <-- use mkm here instead 
            processedMetadata[mkm[key]] = value; // <-- use mkm here instead
        }
    }

    return processedMetadata as MetadataResponse<T>;
}

Playground link to code

I have been able to do it with these types:
const MetadataKeys = {
  NATURE: 'nature' as const,
  BUDGET_YEAR: 'budget_year' as const,
}

const metadataKeysMapper = {
  cdNatureza: MetadataKeys.NATURE,
  natureza: MetadataKeys.NATURE,
  cd_natureza: MetadataKeys.NATURE,
  SiglaNatureza: MetadataKeys.NATURE,
  nuAnoOrcamento: MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR,
  ordem_orcamentaria: MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR,
  nu_ano_orcamento: MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR,
  Orcamento: MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR,
  anoOrcamento: MetadataKeys.BUDGET_YEAR,
};

type MetadataKeysMapper = typeof metadataKeysMapper;
type MetadataKeysMapperKeys = keyof MetadataKeysMapper;

type MapVal<T, V> = {
  [p in keyof T]: V
}

type Metadata<
    K extends MetadataKeysMapperKeys, V
> = MapVal<Pick<MetadataKeysMapper, K>, V>;

type Result<V, K extends MetadataKeysMapperKeys> = Record<MetadataKeysMapper[K], V>;

I use the above in processMetadata;
export function processMetadata<V, K extends MetadataKeysMapperKeys>(
  metadata: Metadata<K, V>,
): Result<V, K> | null {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries<V>(metadata)) {
    if (key in metadataKeysMapper && value) {
      const resultKey: MetadataKeysMapper[K] = metadataKeysMapper[key as K];
      return {
        [resultKey]: value
      } as Result<V, K>;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

And here you can see that everything works as expected:
const result1 = processMetadata({ natureza: 'comum' });
console.log(result1?.nature); // OK "comum"
console.log(result1?.budget_year); // ERROR

const result2 = processMetadata({ nuAnoOrcamento: 'comum' });
console.log(result2?.nature); // ERROR
console.log(result2?.budget_year); // OK "comum"

